# Change existing MySQL data to timestamp

Tags: mysql

In my database, I have a column called *date*.  At the moment, that column contains the date in the following format:

> dd/mm/yyyy

Is there anything I can run to convert this into a unix timestamp? I.e.

01/07/2003 becomes 1057017600

There are about 20,000 rows of historical data and I need to be able to do this through MySQL itself.

I have tried the following, however because the date column is in the wrong format, it doesn't work

```
UPDATE wl_daily
SET
   newdate = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)
```

Comment: Are you attempting to convert the rows, or just get the data from the rows in that form?

Comment: The field is a text field at the moment and the data in there is in the format dd/mm/yyyy.  I simply need to turn it into a timestamp in the database.  I guess you would say i am trying to convert the data in the row/field

Answer (score 2):

You could create a new column (let's say we call it newdate), fill it with your olddate column, drop the old one and rename newdate.

```
ALTER TABLE  `mytable` ADD  `newdate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ;
UPDATE `mytable` set newdate=UNIX_TIMESTAMP( STR_TO_DATE(olddate,  '%d/%m/%Y' ) );
ALTER TABLE `mytable` DROP `olddate`;
ALTER TABLE  `mytable` CHANGE  `newdate`  `olddate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's used 0000-00-00 00:00:00 for every row